# Install Vuze ISO on pre-existing vitual machine

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have an SAP environment on a Vuze Windows 2012 R2 VM and the when i start the ECC the disp+work.exe fails and stops. This is because SQL Server 2014 "Standard" is installed and SAP only support "Enterprise" editions of SQL Server - as per [note 63988](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/62988).

My Microsoft Partnership is not valid for an enterprise key so I have an option to deploy with Vuze. Though the only option I see is to deploy SQL Server 2014 Enterprise as its own VM not actually install it on the existing VM.

Does anyone know about deploying the ISO's on Vuze to an existing VM or if I do deploy SQL Server 2014 as its own VM, will I be able to point SAP on VM "Y" the the SQL Server on VM "X"?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

my MSDN subscription finally came through and now i have access to an Enterprise download =D